# How to know when promise succeeds

Tags: angularjs

I have this code

```
$http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
  success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.status = status;
    $scope.providers = data;                
  }).
  error(function(data, status) {
    $scope.providers2 = data || "Request failed";
    $scope.status = status;
});
```

i would like to do something once my promise resolves, how can i check that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `success` and `error` callbacks are just specialized promise resolvers, so you can just put whatever code you want to run directly in those callbacks, as those callbacks only get called when the promise gets resolved.

Additionally, the promise returned by the `$http` method has a `then` method on it which you can use:

```
$http(/* args */).
  then(function(response) { /* gets run when promise is resolved */ }).
  success(successCallback).
  error(errorCallback);
```